# Domain objects with serialVersionID?

Tags: java, database, serialization

I'm can only persist objects to DB if `implements Serializable`, even if I don't add a `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` or similar.

Question: do I have to set this serialID mandatory? What are the drawbacks if I don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First what is SerialVersionUID and is it mandatory?
```

The serialVersionUID is used as a version control in a Serializable class. If you do not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, JVM will do it for you automatically, based on various aspects of your Serializable class, as described in the [Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

```
Drawbacks if I dont?
```

The default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details and may vary from different JVM implementation, and result in an unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during the deserialization process.

So to avoid this it is better to specify `serialVersionUID` for your serialization and deserialization process

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `serialVersionUID` to make an object serializable. It's only needed when you need to be able to read objects serialized using an old version of the class, or to maintain the serialization format when you make some minor changes (like the ordering of the fields, for example).

I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2013/07/26/stop-with-serialVersionUID/) (in French sorry, but [google translate](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2013/07/26/stop-with-serialVersionUID/&act=url) could help) about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not mandatory. Eclipse shows the same warning when I crete a class that extends JFrame. I always add `@SuppressWarnings("serial")`.

Comment: You might as well disable that warning entirely in the workspace settings then :/ I'd rather just let Eclipse generate the default serialVersionUID in stead of adding the annotation.